# Cloud based NoSql services

Tags: cloud, cloud-hosting, nosql

Title says it all.

I'm trying to track some user behavior on an internal tool(website) my company uses.  Ideally I'd like to just store some json data and be able to query it.  We are currently using sql server and I don't really want to install/host a whole different database to do this simple task. (yes I could store it on sql server but this isn't relational/structured data and could change often).

It would be really nice to simply have my javascript post some data to some cloud base service and have it stored off site somewhere.

Here's what I've looked at so far.

[this](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2012/121912-cloud-databases-265224.html?page=2)

[and this](http://readwrite.com/2011/01/12/7-cloud-based-database-service#awesm=~oB8J2JVYBJiPaP)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both Parse (https://parse.com/) and Kinvey (http://www.kinvey.com/) are NoSQL services.  Both of these are examples of [Mobile Back End as a Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backend_as_a_service) (MBaaS or BaaS), which sounds more or less what you are looking for.

Comment: Do these provide the ability to do indexed searching?   These tool seem more like a development framework(mobile push notifactions etc). I think i'm looking for something more nosql specific(mongodb, couchdb, ...)

Comment: Parse handles indexing for you [http://blog.parse.com/2013/03/19/implementing-scalable-search-on-a-nosql-backend/] [https://parse.com/questions/about-indexing-fields] [https://www.parse.com/questions/indexing-fields-on-objects].  You're right though that they aren't focused specifically on NoSQL and provide other functionality that you aren't interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [Amisa server](http://www.amisalabs.com) is offered as a service with a 30 day free trial. The service is not free because of the underlying hardware cost. Plans start as low as $15 per month. The express edition of the software is totally free. Of course you still have to host it somewhere at a cost.

Comment: This isn't NoSql.  you're right about the hosting costs.  I'll modify the question.